# Get data with condition

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

```
declare @t table (
    Id      int ,
    Section int,
    Moment  date
);

insert into @t values
(   1   ,   1   , '2014-01-01'),
(   2   ,   1   , '2014-01-02'),
(   3   ,   1   , '2014-01-03'),
(   4   ,   1   , '2014-01-04'),
(   5   ,   1   , '2014-01-05'),

(   6   ,   2   , '2014-02-06'),
(   7   ,   2   , '2014-02-07'),
(   8   ,   2   , '2014-02-08'),
(   9   ,   2   , '2014-02-09'),
(   10  ,   2   , '2014-02-10'),

(   11  ,   3   , '2014-03-11'),
(   12  ,   3   , '2014-03-12'),
(   13  ,   3   , '2014-03-13'),
(   14  ,   3   , '2014-03-14'),
(   15  ,   3   , '2014-03-15');
```

getting data like this

```
select * from @t

Id  Section Moment
1   1   2014-01-01
2   1   2014-01-02
3   1   2014-01-03
4   1   2014-01-04
5   1   2014-01-05
6   2   2014-02-06
7   2   2014-02-07
8   2   2014-02-08
9   2   2014-02-09
10  2   2014-02-10
11  3   2014-03-11
12  3   2014-03-12
13  3   2014-03-13
14  3   2014-03-14
15  3   2014-03-15
```

But i want data like this.group by 3 and Section    wise

if ant Section  have 5 rows there will create 2 group.

```
Id  Section Moment  Group by 3
1   1   1/1/2014    1
2   1   1/2/2014    1
3   1   1/3/2014    1
4   1   1/4/2014    2
5   1   1/5/2014    2
6   2   2/6/2014    3
7   2   2/7/2014    3
8   2   2/8/2014    3
9   2   2/9/2014    4
10  2   2/10/2014   4
11  3   3/11/2014   5
12  3   3/12/2014   5
13  3   3/13/2014   5
14  3   3/14/2014   6
15  3   3/15/2014   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and arithmetic.  The following enumerates *within* each section:

```
select (row_number() over (partition by section order by moment) + 2) / 3, t.*
from @t;
```

Then applying `dense_rank()` gets what you want:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by section, tempcol) as group3,
       t.*
from (select (row_number() over (partition by section order by moment) + 2) / 3 as tempcol, t.*
      from t
     ) t
order by id
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4d719f7153cdb12b2b69d32bfda83f7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Sir,your answer max to max close to my desired answer but difference this ,fist column id should increase .                                                                        (No column name) Id Section Moment
1  8 2 2014-02-08
2   9 2 2014-02-09
2 10 2 2014-02-10
1 11 3 2014-03-11
1 12 3 2014-03-12
1 13 3 2014-03-13
2 14 3 2014-03-14
2 15 3 2014-03-15

Comment: @radhasingh . . . This returns *exactly* what you want, except that the "group 3" values are in the first column rather than the last column, so they are easier to see.

Comment: please help me in this topic                                                                                             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742413/get-qurter-wise-data-with-dynamic-data

Answer (score 1):

There might be mistake in interpretion but till where acknowledge the problem i beleive u are looking for this.I have done it using cursor .Hope it helps u .

```
DECLARE @i int =0 -- row count 
DECLARE @GroupCount int=1 
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Section int
DECLARE @Moment DateTime


declare @temp table (
    SNO int,
    Id      int ,
    Section int,
    Moment  date,
    GroupedIn nvarchar(200)
);
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Id,Section,Moment       
FROM @t 
WHERE Section = 3 --suppose 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Id,@Section,@Moment  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
Set @i=@i+1

Insert into @temp values(@i,@Id,@Section,@Moment,'G'+CONVERT(nvarchar(20),@GroupCount))
      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Id,@Section,@Moment   
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor 

Select * from @temp
```

Comment: Hi Rohan ,please help me in this problem          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742413/get-qurter-wise-data-with-dynamic-data

Comment: Sure madame looking for it @radhasingh